# Recommend .net based CMS for an editable tree (taxonomy classification)

Tags: .net, content-management-system, orchardcms

That should be simple web site but with an editable tree. This tree will have 4-6 levels. This is taxonomy classification. Also leafs of the tree are put in categories adding the second classification so that there is filtering of these leafs by those categories.

It seems that Orchard CMS suits to this. Create Module to create custom editing in Admin for those nodes to specify their position in the tree and put them in the categories, etc.

What do you think?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi, Sly. Thank you for your comment. I'll take this into account for future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure of your requirements but maybe orchard might be suitable, but you may have to install the right modules.

The [Taxonomies](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Taxonomies) module allows you to define a taxonomy (like hierarchical tags) and once they are defined anyone posting content like blog posts, pages etc can select where in the hierarchy they belong.

Here is a video explaining it :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3jhgTeiEtw

The [Chapters](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Chapters) module may also be relevant, it allows you to add a hierarchical pages. You can make a book and then add chapters to it. It allows gives you a nice generated index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Looked at Taxonomies module. It is great, will try to use it. But nodes in the tree should be a content itself and in Taxonomy module it is distinguished as i understood: there is classification separate from content. 

Chapters module is another interesting suggestion.

Comment: No, terms are full content items. You can add arbitrary parts to them. It's a beautiful thing.

Comment: Have looked at the Taxonomy module closer. Terms really can be content items which is interesting. It seems that it really suits us, except some things. Thank you!