# Orchard Taxonomy Terms variations

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

What is the best way to make various types from Terms in the [Taxonomy Module](http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com) of Orchard CMS, so that the first level can contain only type1, the second level can contain only type2 and so on? So it would look like real taxonomy of Species.

Example:

- Order1

  - Family1

    - Genera1

      - Species1
  - Family2

    - Genera2

      - Species2
    - Genera3

      - SPecies3
- Order2
- (and more)

Where Order1, Order2 are of type Order with unique set of attributes; Family1, Family2 are of type Family with unique set of attributes and so on.

I thought about creating separate ContentPart that would represent the set of attributes and type and add it to ContentType that is created by Taxonomy Module for the vocabulary of a taxonomy. So there would be TaxonomyTypeRecord, TaxonomyTermAttributeTypeRecord (linked with the type) and TaxonomyTermAttributeRecord (linked with the attribute type). After that the set of attributes would be unique for pathes of terms.

That is the continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290106/recommend-net-based-cms-for-an-editable-tree-taxonomy-classification).

---

UPDATE: 
Here is a diagram:

Taxonomy term 0..1 — 0..* Taxonomy term attribute

Taxonomy term attribute 0..* — 1..1 Taxonomy term attribute type (here are possible types of Attributes, e.g. habitant, # of forms etc.)

Taxonomy term attribute type 0..* — 1..1 Taxonomy term type (or rank, e.g. Species, Order, Family, Genera)

Those entities would be ContentPartRecords for a new ContentPart (say TaxonomyTermTypeContentPart) that would be added to the taxonomy ContentType created by Taxonomy module in TaxonomyService.CreateTermContentType().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: there is only one type of term per taxonomy. But I'm not sure I see the scenario.

Comment: Yes, there is only 1 type of term. It is created in run-time per taxonomy in TaxonomyService.CreateTermContentType(). Please see update in the post for a diagram and details of what I want to do to get those variations for Taxonomy Terms. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Here is an idea: did you try to add a taxonomy field to your taxonomy term types?

Comment: There was an idea to create inheritance of ContentPartRecords (TaxonomyTerm <- Species, <- Family, etc). But that did not work for me. Anyway term types items liked with terms should work here.