# Changing behavior of TaxonomyFieldDriver

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to create descendant of some concrete ContentFieldDriver to be used by Orchard on the place of that concrete driver (to change behavior)?

Want to change behavior of TaxonomyFieldDriver (the descendant of ContentFieldDriver) so that it creates a taxonomy term before it creates links between the term and contentitem (TermsPart).

1) Would it be correct to inherit TaxonomyFieldDriver and override the Editor method? What instance would be used by Orchard CMS, both or just one (which one?)?

2) Would it be correct to use instance of TaxonomyFieldDriver in NewTaxonomyFieldDriver (composition)?

**Update**
The TaxonomyFieldDriver is from [Taxonomy module](http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/) and the main thing it does is calling  ITaxonomyService.UpdateTerms which connects Taxonomy Terms with currently edited ContentItem (owner of that TaxonomyField).

All this is the continuation of [Orchard Taxonomy Terms variations post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497438/orchard-taxonomy-terms-variations).

What i'm trying to do is to create terms from editing of some ContentItem.

I want to use future updates of Taxonomy module.

Answer (score 0):

One very important thing to understand about Orchard is that it's not about inheritance but about composition. You can create your own driver, as there doesn't need to be only one. Then again, it's not very clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have updated the post. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: It seems to me that it is better not to use TaxonomyFieldDriver at all and to create a new one. But the new one should use ITaxonomyService.UpdateTerms.

Comment: If you want to replace it you can use the SuppressDependency attribute.